# Viewing very wide files

Tags: solaris, editors, less

I need to view some 5,200 byte wide files.  Is there any tool to make this practical without modifying the file?  Ideally, I'd like to specify which columns I'm viewing.

Comment: Also, files are 10M+ rows.

Comment: If the data is structured you could use `vim`. Just the viewing. You'd have to use `vim`'s search to jump around.

Comment: If you use vim on a file with 5200-character long lines, do ":set nowrap" and ":syntax off", otherwise you will get amazingly poor response times from vim.

Comment: What about `less -S`?

Answer (score 5):

If what you want is to show specific columns only (say columns 1,5 and 12), use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1,$5,$12}' wide_file.txt | less
```

`awk` splits lines into fields automatically and assigns them to variables. The first field is `$1`, the second `$2` etc. By default, it splits at spaces, if you have a different delimiter, tab for example, specify it with `-F`:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print $1,$5,$12}' wide_file.txt | less
```

I have never used Solaris, but according to [this page](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=158440), the default `awk` might not support the `-F` option, in which case you should use `/usr/bin/nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`.

Comment: I think this approach, coupled with a pipe to `less` would be exactly what the OP needs.

Comment: The problem pointed out in that page is that `awk -F` works with Solaris awk for single characters, but not for strings.   The newer awks (nawk, xpg4 awk, or on more recent Solaris versions, GNU gawk) support more features than the classic awk does.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions that will both work well with large files.
(large in terms of line size and in terms of number of lines, doesn't matter)

### Suggestion 1:

You can use a combination of `cut` and `less`.

Using `cut` you can specify 'columns' both by byte position as well as logical position. Actually you can even use character position as well. (difference between byte position ans character position is only relevant if the file contains multi-byte chars).

Lets say you want to view bytes 1200-1270 of each line then you would do:

```
cut -c1200-1270 wide_file.txt | less
```

or if you want to view logical columns 33-37 then you would do

```
cut -f33-37 wide_file.txt | less
```

### Suggestion 2:

You can also use `less` on its own.

Invoke `less` with the -S option, as in

```
less -S wide_file.txt
```

Then you can scroll left or right in the file by doing n + right arrow or n + left arrow where 'n' is the number of positions to scroll.

Lets say you wanted to scroll right 2000 positions. You would then type 2000 and then press the right arrow. Voila!